# Downloading All Images From Amazon S3

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have had great luck so far with learning and implementing uploading pictures to Amazon's S3 service. I am to upload pictures to the server. All with different names, so there is no overwrite of another one.

I am able to download an image, but only with a certain name (i.e. "image.png). I want to download all of the images. Then I am going to put them in a tableView. I just can't find in the documentation, the answer to this question. Here is my code that is able to download 1 image.

```
-(void)download{

    //Creating S3 transfer manager client
    AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];


    //Dowloading actual object
    //Create the NSURL for thte download location.

    NSString *downloadingFilePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory()stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"downloaded-image.png"];
    NSURL *downloadingFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:downloadingFilePath];

    //Construct download request
    AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest *downloadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest new];

    downloadRequest.bucket = @"MyBucketName";
    downloadRequest.key = @"image.png";  //<----- I can only download an image by this name?
    downloadRequest.downloadingFileURL = downloadingFileURL;


    //Download the file
    [[transferManager download:downloadRequest]continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
        if (task.error) {
            if ([task.error.domain isEqualToString:AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain]) {
                switch (task.error.code) {
                    case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled:
                    case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused:

                        break;

                    default:
                        NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
                        break;
                }
            }else{
                //Unknown Error
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
            }
        }
        if (task.result) {
            AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadOutput *downloadOutput = task.result;
            //File downloade successfully
            NSLog(@"Download Output: %@", downloadOutput);
        }
        self.selectedImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:downloadingFilePath];
        return nil;
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`AWSS3` has a method called `- listObjects:`, which returns an instance of `AWSS3ListObjectsOutput`. The `contents` property of `AWSS3ListObjectsOutput` is an array of `AWSS3Object`. You can loop through the array and call `- download:` on each `key` of `AWSS3Object` in order to download all objects in the bucket.

Comment: How would I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take a lazy approach, the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) can copy multiple files and even recursive sub-directories in one command.

There is also the `aws s3 sync` command, which can copy only new or modified files, including sub-directories.

So, you might want to call-out to the CLI to download the pictures and then process them with your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You can download all images from Bucket using AWSS3ListObjectsRequest.
Here is the code.

AWSS3ListObjectsRequest *listObjectsRequest = [AWSS3ListObjectsRequest new];
    listObjectsRequest.bucket = @"YourBucketName";

```
[[s3 listObjects:listObjectsRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task)
 {
    if (task.error)
    {
        [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"listObjects failed: [%@]", task.error);
    }
    else
    {
        AWSS3ListObjectsOutput *listObjectsOutput = task.result;

        for (AWSS3Object *s3Object in listObjectsOutput.contents)
        {
            downloadingFilePath = [[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"download"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:s3Object.key];

            NSURL *downloadingFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:downloadingFilePath];

            AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest *downloadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest new];
            downloadRequest.bucket = @"YourBucketName";
            downloadRequest.key = s3Object.key;
            downloadRequest.downloadingFileURL = downloadingFileURL;

            AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];
            [[transferManager download:downloadRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task)
             {
                 if ([task.error.domain isEqualToString:AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain]
                     && task.error.code == AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"Download paused.");
                 }
                 else if (task.error)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"Upload failed: [%@]", task.error);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                                    {
                                        //_imgNew.image = [ UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",downloadRequest.downloadingFileURL]];
                                    });
                 }
                 return nil;
             }];
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self setUpScrollViews];
            NSLog(@"Set images called");
            [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
        });
    }
    return nil;
}];
```